# Where to get library for Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, wcsf

How can I get library for `Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication` I cannot find it in nuget. I have a copy of v3.0.0.0, is there any latest version after that? Does Microsoft support it anymore?

I found this article online https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709858.aspx 
it says its retired content, and not mentioned where to download it from.

Comment: I think this would be your best bet - http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Web%20Client%20Software%20Factory&referringTitle=Home.  I've seen other forum posts mentionining needing to rebuild in order to work with newer enterprise libraries but I am not sure how much of that is true.  However, source code is located here - http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: This code doesn't have anything to generates CompositeWeb dll

Comment: `Blocks->CompositeWeb->Source->CompositeWeb->CompositeWeb.csproj` sure sounds like it would compile CompositeWeb.dll....

Comment: thanks for pointing that, I was looking at first link you shared. in this second link we have the DLL bu tit is 2.0.2.0, the one i had with me is 3.0.0.0, i was looking for same or latest.